# The product of two diagonizable matrices is another diagonizable matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I guess this question has been asked before but I have not found it. So I will re-ask. I have a diagonal matrix and a symmetric one, both are diagonizable. If I multiply them, would they be always diagonizable or should they fulfil some condition?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: if they commute, they are diagonalizable in a common basis (its even a "iff") and hence the product is diagonalizable in this basis, and its eigenvalues are products of these of the initial matrix

Answer (score 4):

Counterexample: $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$